# Documentation for jQuery UI 1.6

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I can only find the documentation for jQuery UI 1.7

Where is the documentation for the Legacy jQuery UI 1.6 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [google code](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/downloads/list) for the full repository of downloads (from 1.8 -> 1.5). Downloads include source, demos, themes and tests

Answer (score 3):

You can find Slider documentation at http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.6/Slider

Modify the URL to find documentation of other jQuery UI libraries.